# Get-ADUser cross forest search latency

Tags: powershell, active-directory

With PowerShell, I'm trying to do a cross-forest search for an ADUser using `Get-ADUser` with `filter` using one of the name attributes like `givenname` and `surname` or `employeeid` and with a `Measure-Command` I can see that cross-forest search is faster when GC port is not specified. My understanding is that a GC is designed for fetching the results much faster.

Please refer my `Measure-Command` test results below,

[image: GetADUser-MeasureCommand-results]

**Queries:**

1. Why are the GC's results slower in the given example? Is this because of cross-forest search?
2. Does the `Get-ADUser`'s `filter` parameter work faster on some attributes than others, like having some order of precedence of AD attributes?
3. Is it possible a successive search on a cross-forest will be faster in some cases? (with caching features)

Any information or reference is highly appreciated.

Comment: For the results to be comparable, you need to at least ensure your querying the same Domain Controller. Do `$server = Get-ADDomainController -Service GlobalCatalog -Discover`, then repeat your measurements with `-Server "$server`:3268"` and `-Server "$server"` respectively

Comment: Hi Mathias, Yeah, that makes sense. I'll get back with new results in some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that a GC is designed for fetching the results much faster.

The GC is designed to find results from your entire AD forest without having to query each domain individually. If you only have one domain in your forest, then there really isn't any reason to use the GC, and there are reasons to *not* use it (since not all attributes are replicated to the GC, like `employeeID`).

> 1. Why are the GC's results slower in the given example? Is this because of cross-forest search?

There are lots of reasons it could be slower. It could just be busy at the moment you performed the query. I could hit a different server on different requests (which is where Mathias' suggestion comes into play). If you have more than one domain in your AD forest, then the GC is simply a bigger database.

If it's returning more results from the GC than from the DC, then that would certainly do it (because of how `Get-ADUser` returns the results). But your searches seem like they should only be returning one result.

> 2. Does the `Get-ADUser`'s `filter` parameter work faster on some attributes than others, like having some order of precedence of AD attributes?

This isn't specific to `Get-ADUser`, but just how AD works. Some attributes are indexed, making queries faster (just like any database). Some attributes are not. The first and last name are indexed, `employeeID` and `extensionAttribute11` are not (meaning that every user account has to be looked at to find a match). You might shave off a little bit of time if you use the `-ResultSetSize` parameter and set it to `1`. This way, AD knows it only has to find one result and will stop looking after it finds one. That may not have any noticeable effect though.

> 3. Is it possible a successive search on a cross-forest will be faster in some cases? (with caching features)

Yes. I've seen this myself. Subsequent identical queries will be much faster. Again, that's pretty normal for any database to behave like that.

If you're worried about performance, I'd stick to using `DirectorySearcher`, like you were doing in your other question. You have a lot more control over what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Gabriel! This is definitely going to help me in writing AD search scripts in PowerShell.